# How to update a branched out develop branch with updates from the original develop branch?

Tags: git, github

Illustrated with the git flow diagram below:

1. I have an original develop branch (develop) that branched out to another develop branch (develop-2) that will be pulled into develop in the very far future.
2. I am allowed to perform pull requests on these develop branches (develop and develop-2), but not allowed to edit them directly.
3. I need an update that has occurred in develop after the branching out of develop-2 to add a new feature to develop-2.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: If you need *only* some specific commits from `develop`, `git cherry-pick` looks like the best tool here, but if the other changes from `develop` are not a liability it might be easier to just do a PR `develop > develop2`.

Comment: Hi @RomainValeri, if I do that, my final PR `develop-2 > develop` won't be affected right? Both `develop` and `develop-2` will have continuous development before PR `develop-2 > develop`

Comment: If feature1 contains the material needed by develop2, then it could be merged into develop2 (as well as develop1). But in general maintaining independent long lived branches as in your diagram is a really bad idea, leading to massive merge conflicts when you finally merge develop2 into develop1. You can mitigate by doing frequent merges of develop1 into develop2 but then one has to wonder why you have develop2 at all.

Comment: Nice diagram, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

> if I do that, my final PR develop-2 > develop

It should not, provided the PR is done after develop2 is *rebased* on top of the target branch (develop)

That rebase will get rid of any duplicate commit (like one introduced by a cherry-pick or a previous PR).
Then a PR from develop2 to develop can take place.

Comment: I only proposed a rebate at the end, before the far away develop2 PR